# gradient of function from vector to scalar

Tags: matlab, vector, gradient, scalar

I need to write a scalar function that gets a vector with unknown length. I have made an example:

```
%gets vector and returns x1^1 + x2^2 + ... + xn^n
function [ output ] = func2( x )
u=0;
for j = 1 : length(x)
     u = u + x(j)^j;
end
output = u;
end
```

and

```
%gets vector and returns sin(x1) + sin(x2) + ... + sin(xn)
function func = func1( x )
    func = sum(sin(x));
end
```

but when I try to calculate gradient of this function I get 0 for example:

```
func1([1,2,3]) = -0.865837027279448
```

but

```
gradient(func1([1,2,3]),[1,2,3]) = 0
```

I am looking for a way to implement gradient(func1,x) and get cos(x(1)) cos(x(2)) ... (cos(x(n)) so in the example above it suppose to be:

```
gradient(func1([1,2,3]),[1,2,3]) = [cos(1),cos(2),cos(3)]
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Post the input you are trying with for the `sin` case

Comment: Any vector : >> func1([1,2,3])

Comment: `sum(sin([1 2 3]))` returns `1.8919` and not `0` so clearly your input wasn't `[1 2 3]`. You mentioned `0`, what did you input to get that number?

Comment: The question is about gradient. I get 0 when I try execute something like gradient(func1([1,2,3]),[1,2,3]).

Comment: I am looking for a way to get gradient(func1,x) = cos(x(1)) + cos(x(2))+.. So for the gradient(func1([1,2,3]),[1,2,3]) I suppose to get -0.86583702.

Comment: Okay I'll investigate further, but the use of the `gradient` function wasn't mentioned in your original question. Please update your question with what you have above.

Comment: use code blocks, not quote blocks

Comment: Okay I don't think I know about gradients enough to answer the question. Are you sure it's `-0.8658` instead of `0.5399`? Also, why don't you do all this symbolically?

Comment: vector with unknown length.

Comment: right but you can create symbols with variable lengths IIRC....

Comment: The function `gradient` just gives you the gradient of the matrix, not of the underlying function that is used to calculate the matrix.  You may want to try working out the analytical gradients by hand, or using a finite-difference approximation.

Comment: but if I do this: func1 = @(x,y,z) sin(x)+sin(y)+sin(z);
grad1 = @(x,y,z) gradient(fun1, [x,y,z]); and run it as >> grad1(x,y,z) - It works! I get  cos(x)  cos(y)  cos(z)